# Writing data containing quoted strings into CSV file does not separate rows properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

There is a code that saves data to a .csv file.

```py
import io
import csv
 
a = """string1,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.654515119023E12,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,6.0,1.0
"string2;""=?KOI8-R?a?aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa/aaaa=?=\"",1.0,1.0,1.0,1.654515151681E12,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,2.0,1.0
string3,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.654515072483E12,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,6.0,1.0
string4,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.654515072483E12,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,6.0,1.0
string5,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.654515072483E12,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,6.0,1.0
"""
 
csv_file = open("test.csv", "w", encoding='utf8', newline='')
writer_csv = csv.writer(csv_file)
 
cr = csv.reader(a.splitlines())
for row in list(cr):
    writer_csv.writerow(row)
```

```
string1,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.654515119023E12,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,6.0,1.0
"string2;""=?KOI8-R?a?aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa/aaaa=?="",1.0,1.0,1.0,1.654515151681E12,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,2.0,1.0
string3,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.654515072483E12,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,6.0,1.0
string4,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.654515072483E12,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,6.0,1.0
string5,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.654515072483E12,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,6.0,1.0
"
```

Those subsequent lines stick to the second line, how to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

The quoted string in the 2nd line isn't quoted properly.  It works with the following:

```
a = '''string1,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.654515119023E12,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,6.0,1.0
"string2;""=?KOI8-R?a?aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa/aaaa=?=""",1.0,1.0,1.0,1.654515151681E12,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,2.0,1.0
string3,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.654515072483E12,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,6.0,1.0
string4,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.654515072483E12,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,6.0,1.0
string5,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.654515072483E12,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,6.0,1.0
'''
```

Explanation:

The double quote before `string2` starts a field.  The `""` after `string2;` is properly escaped and treated as a one embedded double quote when read in by `csv.reader`, but the only other double quotes later in the string represent another embedded double quote, and never close the field.  Switching to triple single quotes around the string, and adding a 3rd double quote after the `""` embedded quote closes the field.

Full example:

```py
import csv

a = '''string1,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.654515119023E12,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,6.0,1.0
"string2;""=?KOI8-R?a?aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa/aaaa=?=""",1.0,1.0,1.0,1.654515151681E12,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,2.0,1.0
string3,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.654515072483E12,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,6.0,1.0
string4,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.654515072483E12,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,6.0,1.0
string5,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.654515072483E12,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,6.0,1.0
'''
 
with open("test.csv", "w", encoding='utf8', newline='') as csv_file:
    writer_csv = csv.writer(csv_file)
    cr = csv.reader(a.splitlines())
    writer_csv.writerows(cr)
```

Output to test.csv:

```
string1,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.654515119023E12,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,6.0,1.0
"string2;""=?KOI8-R?a?aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa/aaaa=?=""",1.0,1.0,1.0,1.654515151681E12,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,2.0,1.0
string3,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.654515072483E12,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,6.0,1.0
string4,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.654515072483E12,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,6.0,1.0
string5,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.654515072483E12,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,6.0,1.0
```

Comment: I got the idea and did this:  re.sub(r'\\”', '""', a)